# Simple RGB to Gray program crashes

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, dev-c++

I am trying to make a simple conversion of an image from RGB to Grayscale with OpenCV. I am using dev-cp on windows, here is the code:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  char* imageName = argv[1];

  Mat image;
  image = imread( imageName );

  Mat gray_image;
  cvtColor(image,gray_image,CV_RGB2GRAY);
}
```

When I execute it, seems it crashes on the `cvtColor`.

Comment: "it crashes " - means ? you get an exception ? a segfault ?

Comment: In windows it gives nothing, I think it is a Segmentation Fault. It just says: "the program has stopped working".

Comment: How many channels does image have? Are you sure you are loading a color Image?

Comment: @David_D - imread without any flags(==IMREAD_COLOR) *should* force a 24bit bgr image

Comment: Yeah, it is a .jpg image and I tried also with `imread( imageName, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR );`

Comment: opencv version ? which special mingw compiler are you using ? (also, be careful with mingw, - support from the opencv side for using it seems to be fading away rapidly)

Comment: I am using openCV 2. And x86_64-w64-mingw32.

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  if (argc < 2) return 0;

  char* imageName = argv[1];

  Mat image;
  image = imread( imageName );

  if(image.empty()) return 0;

  Mat gray_image;
  cvtColor(image,gray_image,CV_RGB2GRAY);

  imshow("image",image);
  cv::waitKey(0);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what does it do? does it crash or does it just quit? can you add std::cout before each line to find the place where it crashes?

Comment: As I said in the question, it crashes in the `cvtColor`.

Comment: sorry couldn't know that it still crashes in MY version of the code, since you only said "keeps not working". in your original code you dont test whether the image was loaded at all, which is very often the cause of a crashing cvtColor function (providing an empy mat).